# What is chrome path inside docker ubuntu image

Tags: docker, google-chrome, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

what is the chrome installation path inside docker container,usually its stores in opt in linux system but i dont have this directory in my image, so im unable to find the path.

this is the command i used for docker image:

```
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
dpkg --unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
apt-get install -f -y
```

Comment: Code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only this works for me, use -x command and specify the dir ,instead of --unpack,

RUN wget  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/${CHROME_PACKAGE} && \
    dpkg-deb -x ${CHROME_PACKAGE} / && \
    apt-get install -f -y

Answer (score 0):

wget is a download tool. It is always useful to know what the command is before you run it :). In this case, you are downloading chrome, unpacking the file, and then installing chrome. Unless you specify the path to downloads, get downloads to the current dir. Using docker or not using docker doesn't mean much too.

*UPDATE*: The directory to install chrome to is the /usr/bin/ dir. You will need sudo. So your full command would be `sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb -P /usr/bin/ && \ dpkg --unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \ apt-get install -f -y`, or you could first do `cd /usr/bin/`, and then `sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \ dpkg --unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \ apt-get install -f -y`. You might need to modify the command as needed. Hope this helps:)

Comment: great thx for your reply, but how i can specify path for installation
what works for me this one 
dpkg-deb -x google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb /mydir this command was fine and i saw the extracted folder but using the one in question i couldn't find any chrome folder in root or any where how installation was successful

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if that doesn't work, and I'll be glad to help:)

Comment: thx for answering i did that solution, but it didnt install chrome in that directory again